# How to find X,Y coordinates on Half Doughnut Chart JS react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I've got the doughnut part of the chart complete and the gauge needle. I want to add this circular pointer on the doughnut instead of the needle. I was able to draw the circular pointer but couldn't find the right X,Y coordinates to place the pointer.

Here is the [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/half-doughnut-chart-example-forked-yzjhvw?file=/src/App.js)

Here in the below image, the circle should be placed at the gauge needle pointer
[image]

The code I've used is the following for the circular pointer.

```js
const pointer = {
  id: "pointer",
  afterDatasetsDraw: (chart) => {
    const { ctx } = chart;

    var data = chart._metasets[0].data[0];

    var radius = data.innerRadius + (data.outerRadius - data.innerRadius) / 2;

    var centerX = data.x;
    var centerY = data.y;

    const angle = (180 / 1000) * speed;
    // this thing needs to be fixed
    var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI);
    var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI);

    ctx.save();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 6;
    ctx.arc(x, y, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();
  }
};
```

Target to achive:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want 75% of 180 Degrees *(because the speed = 75)*:

```
const angle = Math.PI * ( speed / 100)  +  Math.PI;
```

And than `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` expect a radiant value([link to mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin)), which you already have, so no multiplication with `Math.PI` is needed anymore.

```
  var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos( angle );
  var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin( angle );
```

**Full working demo *(Updated Example, now with animation)*:**

```js
const speed = 75;
let animationAngle = 0;

var pointer = {
    id: 'pointer',
    defaults:{
     percentage: 0,
     maxAngle: 0
    },
    afterDraw: function(chart, args, opt) {
      const { ctx } = chart;

      var data = chart._metasets[0].data[0];
      var radius = data.innerRadius + (data.outerRadius - data.innerRadius) / 2;

      var centerX = data.x;
      var centerY = data.y;

      const angle = (Math.PI * ( speed / 100) * chart.options.plugins.pointer.percentage)  +  Math.PI;
      
      var x = centerX + radius * Math.cos( angle );
      var y = centerY + radius * Math.sin( angle );

      ctx.save();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 6;
      ctx.arc(x, y, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
    },
}

var options = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [20, 50, 30],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 164, 46, 1)',
            'rgba(46, 204, 113, 1)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1)',
            'rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1)',
            'rgba(255, 255, 255 ,1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 0
    }]},
    options: {
      cutout: 80,
      rotation: -90,
      circumference: 180,
      animation:{
        onProgress: function(context){
            if(context.initial){
                this.options.plugins.pointer.percentage = context.currentStep / context.numSteps;
            }
        }
      },
      
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: { display: false },
      
      plugins:{ 
        tooltip: {  enabled: false },
        pointer: {currentAngle: 1}
      }
    }, 
    plugins:[pointer]
}

const chart = document.getElementById('chart1')
new Chart(chart, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:184px">
   <canvas id="chart1" width="500" height="184"></canvas>
<div>
```